# Email send by cakePHP, How can set administrator email address in from variable?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I write a function for registration, after registration I want to send a email from administrator mail address. How can I will set administrator email address in a variable?

this is my function:

```
function registration() {
        $this->loadModel('User');
        $this->loadModel('Role');
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->set($this->request->data);
            if ($this->User->validates()) {
    $mail_data = $this->User->save($this->request->data);


                $owneremail = $this->request->data['info@gmail.com'];
                $from = $owneremail;
                $subject = "Technician registration";
                $user_name = $mail_data['User']['name'];
                $email_user = $mail_data['User']['email'];
                $password = $this->request->data['User']['password'];
                $to = array($mail_data['User']['email']);
                $mail_content = __('Name:', 'beopen') . $user_name . PHP_EOL .
                        __('Email:', 'beopen') . $email_user . PHP_EOL .
                        __('Password:', 'beopen') . $password . PHP_EOL .
                        __($url = Router::url(array("controller" => "users", "action" => "login"), true));

                sendEmail($from, $user_name, $to, $subject, $mail_content);

 $msg = '<div class="alert alert-success">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
   <strong> User Created succeesfully </strong>
   </div>';
            } else {
                $msg = $this->generateError($this->User->validationErrors);
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash($msg);
            // return $this->redirect('create');
        }
        $this->set('roles', $this->Role->find("list"));
    }
```

By this code I can't send email from administrator mail address

Comment: "How can I will set website owner email address in a variable?" That sentence does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print the array : `$this->request->data`. I think there is no index like `info@gmail.com` It seems you try to set an email in `from` attribute. So just assign email to $from. Try this:

step1: remove  `$owneremail = $this->request->data['info@gmail.com'];` line

step2: change  `$from = $owneremail;` to

```
  $from = 'info@gmail.com';
```

N.B: Study on basic of array and set real email to test email function.